# Rigify Generating Broken Armature?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, rigify

new to Blender but quite familiar with Maya. Been learning Blender 2.8 and all was going well until I hit the Rigify. For whatever reason it seems to have not attached the blue joints to the green bones, and not to attach the green bones to the mesh.

When I move the green lines in any way it has 0 effect on the mesh, basically all I can do on the arms and legs is translate the blue circular joints around to create the illusion of rotation. The green guys do nothing.

I've lost track of how many Rigify tutorials I've watched and how many times I've restarted, even in a fresh scene with a different character. What could I be doing wrong here?

Running Blender 2.81 on Windows 10, using the basic human metarig, have not deleted anything from the Metarig, positioned metarig in edit mode, Python auto-run is enabled.

[image: Note the green bones poutside the arms.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is odd. It looks like the Rigify rig is set to IK. You have to select one of the bones for the arms in pose mode and set the IK-FK (hand.L) value to 1.00. See picture[image]

You can adjust this for every limb and is one of the useful options of Rigify.Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply! Seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Your welcome! Have fun!